# Autocomplete extender for multiple textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to apply one autocomplete extender for multiple textbox having same `name` attribute, For eg.

I just want to apply same autocomplete extender to all having `name="txtQtyPkgs"`. How I can do this?
My html

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="" id="flex1">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="rowGH03013">
                <td align="Left" class="sorted">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">
                        GH03013</div>
                </td>
                <td align="Left">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">
                        999</div>
                </td>
                <td align="Left">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 161px;">
                        <input align="right" type="text" width="30px" name="txtQtyPkgs" maxlength="3" onblur="IntegerOnly(this.id);"
                            id="QtyPkgs19523"></div>
                </td>
                <td align="Left">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 446px;">
                        <input align="left" type="text" width="300px" class="auto" maxlength="100" name="txtBuyerName"
                            id="Buyer19523"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="erow" id="rowGH03011">
                <td align="Left" class="sorted">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">
                        GH03011</div>
                </td>
                <td align="Left">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">
                        999</div>
                </td>
                <td align="Left">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 161px;">
                        <input align="right" type="text" width="30px" name="txtQtyPkgs" maxlength="3" onblur="IntegerOnly(this.id);"
                            id="QtyPkgs19521"></div>
                </td>
                <td align="Left">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width: 446px;">
                        <input align="left" type="text" width="300px" class="auto" maxlength="100" name="txtBuyerName"
                            id="Buyer19521"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

my xml data

```
<table>
  <userid>23</userid>
  <userdispname>GUJARAT PACKERS LTD</userdispname>
  <usercode>GTPL</usercode>
</table>

<table>
  <userid>26</userid>
  <userdispname>Lipton India Limited</userdispname>
  <usercode>Lipton</usercode>
</table>
<table>
  <userid>27</userid>
  <userdispname>TOSH LTD.</userdispname>
  <usercode>ATosh</usercode>
</table>
<table>
  <userid>28</userid>
  <userdispname>SERVICES INDIA PVT. LTD.</userdispname>
  <usercode>TSI</usercode>
</table>
<table>
  <userid>29</userid>
  <userdispname>Parekh Company</userdispname>
  <usercode>Parekh</usercode>
</table>
<table>
  <userid>30</userid>
  <userdispname>SHREE BALAJI CO.</userdispname>
  <usercode>Balaji</usercode>
</table>
<table>
  <userid>31</userid>
  <userdispname>Kesaria Company</userdispname>
  <usercode>Kesaria</usercode>
</table>
```

my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            AuctoCmplBuyer();
            $(".auto").autocomplete({ source: [AuctoCmpData] });
        });
 function AuctoCmplBuyer() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../service/WebService.asmx/XmlData",
                data: "{strData:'BuyerList'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $(msg).find('Table').each(function () {
                        if (StrData.length != 0) {
                            StrData = StrData + ",";
                        }
                        StrData = '{"id":"' + $(this).find('UserID').text() + '","label":"' + $(this).find('UserDispName').text() + '","value":"' + $(this).find('UserDispName').text() + '"}';
                    });
                }
            });
            AuctoCmpData = StrData;
        }
```

Comment: Add StrData ="["; above $(msg).find(){(...)}; and strData=strData+"]"; after the loop(.each).So your strData will be in the form of [{"";""}].But Now it is in this form {"",""}.Hope u got me

Comment: hi,its worked for me..as i try it on noraml Html..but how i can do this same for textbox inside the flexgride control....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put a common class name for all your textbox and using jQuery autocomplete you can do it.

```
 $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: "../Ajax/AjaxGetData.ashx,
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```

Please refer for more.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

What I am doing is to make a class called auto and assign it to all of the text box. so when ever the user enters the value it will be going to the handler page (asp.net) or u can use a .php page. In that handler page I am selecting data from database using the `like` operator of Sql.After selecting the values just `Response.Write()` (in asp.net) or `echo`(in php please refer) to send the data.The data is send in the `JSON` format

```
[ { "id":"XYZ" , "label":"XYZ" , "value": "XYZ"}]
```

The above is the format of JSON

For all auto suggest you might have a lot of data.To do so you have to get the total number of results returned after the execution of the query and make a loop.Initialize a string variable with the default value as `"["` to the start and append the string with `{"id":"Data","label:Data","value":"data"}`(this constitutes a JSON object).If it is having more than you just add a `,` and do looping at the end add `"]"` to string.

So ur array will be in the format of

```
  [ { "id":"XYZ1" , "label":"XYZ1" , "value": "XYZ1"}, { "id":"XYZ2" , "label":"XYZ2" , "value": "XYZ2"}]
```

The `[' denotes the starting of array and ']' denotes the end
The`{` denotes the starting of object and '}' denotes the end

Pls refer  [JSON](http://www.json.org/)  to know more

Comment: in my case i have collection of the data (array)..than making call every time..how i can do this with array ....

Comment: yes it will be like that only . There may be a lot of values.So you need to add the values.Pls chk the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            AuctoCmplBuyer();
Auctocomplete functionality to each textbox
            $(".auto").autocomplete({ source: AuctoCmpData });
        });

function AuctoCmplBuyer() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../service/TWWebService.asmx/XmlData",
                data: "{strData:'BuyerList'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $(msg).find('Table').each(function () {
                        rowObj = new Object();
                        rowObj.col1 = $(this).find('UserDispName').text() + '-' + $(this).find('UserID').text();
                        AuctoCmpData.push(rowObj);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

i am doing in this way ...i am not getting the way you said "harie"

Comment: u r here using XML. I just replace XML and u r loading the entire values during Page load. I just suggested the way to get data only when the user press the key . Am i rite?

Comment: yes..i fallowed ur method but not get the way i want..please see the updated question for reff and tell me ..where i am wrong